# Using Django admin template tags

Tags: django, django-admin, django-1.5

I wanna use templatetags of `contrib.admin` in `Djnago`. To do this added required things to `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings.py.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    ...
)
```

But when I try to use one of the tags, it says `Invalid block tag: 'x'`. I tried to use `'search_form'` and `'admin_list_filter'` tags and I saw the error for them.

```
{% block search %}{% search_form cl %}{% endblock %}

{% for spec in cl.filter_specs %}{% admin_list_filter cl spec %}{% endfor %}
```

What may I be missing?

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The template tags from the Django admin are not really re-usable. To use the `search_form` tag, you would have to provide a `ChangeList` instance, which is very tightly coupled to the Django admin.

If you were able to reuse the tag, you would have to [load](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/builtins/#load) the tag library first.
The `search_form` tag is in [`django.contrib.admin.templatetags.admin_list`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.5/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py). Therefore, you would have to load the `admin_list` tags before could use it.

```
{% load admin_list %}
{% search_form cl %}
```

Comment: Thank you for solution. I also wanna ask another question about `tags`. Now i can use them in my custom admin page by loading `admin_list.py`. But I can't use `html` and `static files` in admin. Do I have to move files that I use to my static file folder from admin folders? Can't I use them without moving. For example `search_form` returns a `html` content but i guess it does not see `admin/search_form.html` path and it returns nothing

Comment: You would be better to ask that as a new question. It's too long and complex to answer in the comments.

Comment: Sorry I asked the question and it is on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17234813/accessing-static-files-in-django-admin-packages